# Maven plugin MOJO brakes the build when resolving dependency

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

Example to reproduce: https://github.com/g4s8/example-plugin

I'm trying to create Maven Plugin which works with compiled test classes. Before accessing `test-classes` files it has to resolve the classpath. I observed classpath resolving mechanism in `surefire-maven-plugin` sources, but my implementation is simpler (see https://github.com/g4s8/example-plugin/blob/master/example-maven-plugin/src/main/java/wtf/g4s8/RunWithClasspathMojo.java#L43-L49):

```java
// resolve all dependencies for current project
final Set<Artifact> artifacts = this.repos.resolve(
        new ArtifactResolutionRequest()
            .setArtifact(this.project.getArtifact())
            .setLocalRepository(this.lrep)
            .setRemoteRepositories(this.project.getRemoteArtifactRepositories())
            .setResolveTransitively(true)
).getArtifacts();
```

This plugin is working fine, but after first run it breaks all next build of the project (see [example-project](https://github.com/g4s8/example-plugin/tree/master/example-project)): `maven-jar-plugin` is failing with error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin:3.0.2:jar (default-jar) on project example-project: You have to use a classifier to attach supplemental artifacts to the project instead of replacing them. -> [Help 1]

If I disable my plugin with `-DskipTests` or just remove 
the code to resolve dependencies, target project will be built successfully.

I suppose `ArtifactRepository.resolve` somehow affects current build.

What's wrong with this code and how to resolve dependencies classpaths for Maven project from plugin correctly?

Comment: Why don't you use `project.getArtifacts()` on the injected Maven project?

Comment: @JFMeier I tried to use `project.getArtifacts()` but it's returning empty set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the top line of the Mojo (where you also define the phase etc.), you need to set the `@requiresDependencyResolution` to `test`.

Comment: Thanks, it's working with `@Mojo(name = "test", defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.TEST, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.TEST)
`